# xCode - isEqualToString returning true even when debugger shows both strings do not match?

Tags: objective-c, audio, nsstring

I have a very simple isEqualTostring condition inside a button press function using the name of a sound that was last played, and the name of the sound that is about to be played:

```
if([lastSoundPlayed isEqualToString:soundString])
{
    [audioPlayer stop];
}
else
{
    //sound player stuff
    lastSoundPlayed = soundString;//set lSP to match this sound
}
```

The lastSoundPlayed variable is initially set to the @"z4;3b", a junk value to make sure it would never match any of the real sound names.
My problem is that if I break at the [audioPlayer stop] part and po the 2 strings, it shows that the values were 'z4;3b' and 'alarm'. Clearly different, and yet for the debugger to reach that breakpoint they would need to be the same.

The problem happens from the first time the button is pressed.

Any ideas why it would be showing equality between the 2 strings?

Thanks

Edit: Just tried this:

```
if([@"goodbye" isEqualToString:@"hello"])
{
     //break here
}
```

and it still reached the breakpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Fixed' this myself.

It was because I still had it in Ad-Hoc mode, not debug. I stepped over the breakpoint and realised that it jumped back to the if statement, as though it had ignored it in the first place. Then a bit further down I tried to po the lastSoundPlayed variable and it couldn't access the memory location -